# SXA out of the box Gallery component is not working as expected

Tags: sxa

I am using Sitecore 9.3 and SXA 9.3.
I am trying to add SXA Gallery rendering to a page but I am unable to add images from experience editor into the gallery component.

Step1: Dropped the rendering on the page
[image]

Step2: Clicked on "+" to add a gallery image. Getting the below screen after adding 1 gallery image and click save.

[image]

I am unable to add a picture from media library to Gallery Image and also unable to add more slides to gallery (gallery images). It gives a message "Image not found: #", as shown above. Unable to do anything after that from experience editor. Can anyone please help me with the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a Gallery component in SXA, you need to first create a Gallery item using the *Gallery* template

[image]

which will look like this in the content editor Data folder:
[image]

Then you can add media items under this folder:
[image]

Select Gallery folder as data source while rendering component, it should render like this:

[image]

--------------------------------------------------- **UPDATE** -----------------------------------------------

If we try to add Gallery images directly from the Experience editor, then getting the same error as you reported in the original question. Seems like this is a bug in Sitecore **9.3** and from what I can see this issue is resolved in SXA **10.0** and later. As a workaround in SXA 9.3, consider either using the content editor or alternatively if you need to edit through Experience Editor, consider utilizing the **Edit the related item** button:

[image]

which should allow you to add or modify images and videos in the gallery.

Comment: I created gallery datasource item inside local data folder. I am unable to add more gallery images from experience editor.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the dialog box that is supposed to let you add images on the component doesn't let you do that, it may be:

1. Failing to retrieve an indexed list of images and display those in the view. So one of the things you can do is to capture for related errors in the logs. From there you can find more clues to the underlying issue.
2. Or if you wanted to test the Gallery component, add that component in the Experience Editor and in the local datasource created, open that in the Content Editor instead then add manually the Gallery Image from there.